# check box in listview not working properly

Tags: android

I am implementing the checkbox with listview for every Iten of listview.The Problem i am getting is when I am clicking on any single check box and when i scroll then some other checkboxes which are not clicked also getting clicked randomly. i went through many link on SO but it did'nt solve my problem.

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Client> {

ViewHolder holder = null;
private LayoutInflater inflator = null;
private ArrayList<Client> orderList = null;
ArrayList<View> allViews;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<Client> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    orderList = (ArrayList<Client>) objects;
    inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    allViews = new ArrayList<View>();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listview_add_order, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.txtViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewAddOrder);
        holder.spinnerAddorder = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerAddOrder);
        holder.checkAddorder = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkAddOrder);
        holder.checkAddorder.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        holder.checkAddorder.setTag(holder);
    }

    allViews.add(position, holder.spinnerAddorder);

    holder.checkAddorder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CheckBox cchk = (CheckBox)view;
            ViewHolder checkPosition = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();


            if(cchk.isChecked()) {

                checkPosition.spinnerAddorder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {
                checkPosition.spinnerAddorder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Select Quantity");
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(),R.layout.spinner_add_order_style, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    holder.spinnerAddorder.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    if(holder.checkAddorder.isChecked()) {


        ViewHolder checkPosition = (ViewHolder) holder.checkAddorder.getTag();
        checkPosition.spinnerAddorder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {

        ViewHolder checkPosition = (ViewHolder) holder.checkAddorder.getTag();
        checkPosition.spinnerAddorder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


    Client order = orderList.get(position);

    holder.txtViewName.setText(order.getFirstName());
    return  convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtViewName = null;
    public Spinner spinnerAddorder = null;
    public CheckBox checkAddorder = null;
}

     }
```

my xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:weightSum="2" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewAddOrder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerAddOrder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".8"
    android:background="@drawable/dropdown" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkAddOrder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you show me your xml file of this adapter class ??

Comment: @ChiragPatel This issue will occur because listview recycle its views What Koded101 posted is exactly right.. No need of xml file

Comment: @chirag i added xml file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because of view recycling. What you need to do is maintain an array of say booleans and every time a checkbox is checked toggle the corresponding boolean. Then in your getview check the corresponding boolean array position and set the state of the check box.

Along these lines: I have modified it so it displays correctly. Have not checked what the rest of your code is upto. ^_^

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Client> {

ViewHolder holder = null;
private LayoutInflater inflator = null;
private ArrayList<Client> orderList = null;
ArrayList<View> allViews;

boolean[] checkedStates; //********** NEW ********

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<Client> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    orderList = (ArrayList<Client>) objects;
    inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    allViews = new ArrayList<View>();

    checkedStates = new boolean[objects.size()]; //********** NEW ********
}

@Override   //********** NEW ******** position argument is now final 
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listview_add_order, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.txtViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewAddOrder);
        holder.spinnerAddorder = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerAddOrder);
        holder.checkAddorder = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkAddOrder);
        holder.checkAddorder.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        holder.checkAddorder.setTag(holder);
    }

    allViews.add(position, holder.spinnerAddorder);

    holder.checkAddorder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

              checkedStates[position] = !checkedStates[position]; //********** NEW ********
        }
    });

    holder.chechAddorder.setChecked(checkedStates[position]); //********** NEW ********

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Select Quantity");
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(),R.layout.spinner_add_order_style, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    holder.spinnerAddorder.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    if(checkedStates[position]) { //********** NEWEST ******** assuming true is checked and false is unchecked


        ViewHolder checkPosition = (ViewHolder) holder.checkAddorder.getTag();
        checkPosition.spinnerAddorder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {

        ViewHolder checkPosition = (ViewHolder) holder.checkAddorder.getTag();
        checkPosition.spinnerAddorder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


    Client order = orderList.get(position);

    holder.txtViewName.setText(order.getFirstName());
    return  convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtViewName = null;
    public Spinner spinnerAddorder = null;
    public CheckBox checkAddorder = null;
}

     }
```

Comment: What you posted is exactly right, but provide him some piece of code

Comment: yeah its working nice but it updates checked or unchecked state after scrolling the list view

Comment: You mean its still doing the same thing?

Comment: it's working perfectly. it checks or unchecks the correct item but it shows or hides respective spinner only after scrolling listview

Comment: updated now, you needed to change the isChecked line for show/hide. Let me know if its working!

Answer (score 1):

Just set focusable Property = false.
make onClickListener on CheckBox in the adapter.

```
{ <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_alert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
    android:checked="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:padding="7dip" />}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two way data binding to handle checkbox state
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#kotlin

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/rememberMeCheckBox"
android:checked="@={viewmodel.rememberMe}"
```

/>

class LoginViewModel : BaseObservable {
    // val data = ...

```
@Bindable
fun getRememberMe(): Boolean {
    return data.rememberMe
}

fun setRememberMe(value: Boolean) {
    // Avoids infinite loops.
    if (data.rememberMe != value) {
        data.rememberMe = value

        // React to the change.
        saveData()

        // Notify observers of a new value.
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.remember_me)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Override this methods in your adapter:

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = position
```