# Listview button backround issue while scrolling in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a `Listview` which shows Facebook friend image and name.There is a `Button` on each row on the right side to do some operation withe that particular Facebook friend.The `Button` can either have 3 backgrounds based on some condition. Those are as Follows,

1.Set the button background to "Background1.png" if that friend is not invited.

2.Set the button background to "background2.png" if that friend is  invited.

3.Set the button background to "background3.png" if that friend had completed the survey.

I have some given conditions which checks whether the friend is invited or not.Also for the survey thing.Attached screenshot shows what I need actually.

[image]

My problem is the button background changes while scrolling as `Listview` reuses the position.I cant use general views to show it as number of Facebook friend varies and it will show memory issue.
Below is what I have tried so far. Please guide me how to achieve this.

**Code:**

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_listview, null);

            Facebook_FriendImage=(SmartImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
            Facebook_FriendName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
            invite = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.invite);

            invite.setTag(position);

            if (position==2 || position==3) {
                 invite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background1);
             } 
             else if (position==5 || position==8) {
                 invite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background2);
             }
             else {
                 invite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background3);
             }
            //Snippet for loading FB Friend Image
               int loader = R.drawable.no_image;
               Facebook_FriendImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
               Facebook_FriendImage.setImageUrl(GlobalClass.FACEBOOK_FRIEND_IMAGE_URL.get(position), loader);


             //Snippet for Loading FB Friend Name  
             String unicode=new String(GlobalClass.FACEBOOK_FRIEND_NAME.get(position));
          Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "NotoSans-Bold.ttf");
          Facebook_FriendName.setTypeface(font); 
          Facebook_FriendName.setText(unicode);  

            return vi;
        }
```

The if conditions I have given here is just for simplification.

Comment: as you explicitely set the bg res for each position, i don't see why your code wouldn't work. position 0, 1, 4, 6, 7, 9+ have bg3, 2 and 3 have bg1, 5 and 8 have bg2.

Comment: however, if your ifs are simplification and are not the exact code you are using, i'd guess the issue is somewhere there. can you post your actual code?

Comment: @njzk2: You are right my friend.To post here I made a lot of edit in my code and yeah the above code works for this given conditions.

Comment: which implies that you now post your actual code

Answer (score 0):

solution may be this:
simply delete only condition.

```
if(convertView == null)
```

may this help.

you should also try to make new View:

```
View vi = convertView;
if(vi == null) {
    //your code
}
return vi;
```

Comment: the second solution you offer is exactly what they are doing already

Comment: @njzk2, there might be difference in (vi==null)and(convertView==null)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Holder to your ListView like this :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView == null){
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_listview, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.Facebook_FriendImage=(SmartImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
                holder.Facebook_FriendName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
                holder.invite = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invite);
                invite.setTag(position);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            if (position==2 || position==3) {
                 holder.invite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background1);
             } 
             else if (position==5 || position==8) {
                 holder.invite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background2);
             }
             else {
                 holder.invite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background3);
             }
            //Snippet for loading FB Friend Image
               int loader = R.drawable.no_image;
               holder.Facebook_FriendImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        holder.Facebook_FriendImage.setImageUrl(GlobalClass.FACEBOOK_FRIEND_IMAGE_URL.get(position), loader);
             //Snippet for Loading FB Friend Name  
             String unicode=new String(GlobalClass.FACEBOOK_FRIEND_NAME.get(position));
          Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "NotoSans-Bold.ttf");
          holder.Facebook_FriendName.setTypeface(font); 
          holder.Facebook_FriendName.setText(unicode);  

            return convertView;
        }
```

and the class ViewHolder should be like this :

```
class ViewHolder{
    SmartImageView Facebook_FriendImage;
    TextView Facebook_FriendName;
    Button invite;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of view recycling i also faced the same problem. Go through link nelow it solved my problem

[check box in listview not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248940/check-box-in-listview-not-working-properly)